# Insert javascript var inside Rails i18n

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need to display the os version with i18n.

Simple Example,

javascript,

```
var os = "Windows 3.1"

if(os is too old){
  $(".warning").append('<%=t("warning"), version: os%>')
}
```

en.yml,

```
warning: "%{version} version is too old :("
```

I hope you'll notice my point. In here, I want to use the `os` var to rails i18n.

But the Rails can't recognize javascript var :(

Is there a good solution with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [i18n.js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) for translating views dinamically generaded with JavaScript. Your code will not work because `<%=t("warning"), version: os%>` is erb syntax. ERB views are paresed only by backend (rails).

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But our whole app is already using rails i18n. I think maintaining both i18n rails and js should be horrible :(. So My solution was, print the i18n word without %{version} and used jquery .prepend(os)

Comment: The point with i18n.js, is that it makes the normal i18n localizations available in js, so that you don't need to maintain multiple localization frameworks.